# How to restore a time machine backup of a volume whose name contains a slash

Tags: macos, time-machine, filenames

I am trying to restore a volume from a time machine backup on a different machine using tmutil on a Mac.  Unfortunately, the volume I am trying to restore was named "/#defaults".  File names aren't supposed to have a slash in their name, but digging into the backup file in finder, it clearly shows that the inner directory filename is `/#defaults`.  So I need to put on the command line something like `/Volumes/backups/Backups.backupdb/MyMac/Latest//#defaults/*`.  I've tried quoting the string in a variety of ways and there is no apparent way to get the command line to interpret a slash as part of the filename as opposed to be part of the path structure.

So now I am wondering if there is some safe way to change the time machine directory name `/#defaults` to something more palatable, and whether that will even work.

Comment: Have you tried drag & drop? [I can't rename a drive to test, but it works just fine for regular drive/folders]

Comment: @Tetsujin It didn't actually occur to me to use finder to get stuff out of the time machine backup, but it did work.  Still can't associate the new drive with the old backup, as I would have to specify the same folder in the command line.  But I'll take a couple of extra days backing things up as penance for having a drive named so horribly.  Thanks for the suggestion!